# IDLE window gets closed without displaying output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a simple program to determine whether the given number is perfect cube or not. It works well if I run it from command line but when I open it from IDLE that is by just double clicking program.py it processes the input too but closes without displaying the output. any suggestions?

```
ans=0
x=int(input("Enter a number:"))
while (ans*ans*ans < abs(x)):
ans=ans+1

if (ans*ans*ans != abs(x)):
print( str(x) + ' is not a perfect cube ' )
else:
if x<0:
    ans=-ans
print ( ' Cube root of ' + str(x) + ' is ' + str(ans))
print("Thank you")
```

Comment: Ask for user input at the end to stop it from closing\

Comment: tried adding raw_input() but still closes

Comment: You are coding like this is java. No parenthesis needed around conditions.

Comment: @AlfieSmith Try input()

Comment: @AlfieSmith Wait... did you not indent the bodies of your `while` loop and first `if`? If so, you are probably getting a syntax error, which would explain why IDLE is exiting.

Comment: @Natecat I have indent the bodies for while and if.also, if I have a quick look on the IDLE, I can see there's no syntax errors, its giving output too but gets closed without displaying it and input() didnt helped

Comment: input_raw() was not working but input() worked :) thanks @Natecat